# How to use named parameters instead of question marks using jOOQ

Tags: sql, kotlin, jooq

I'm using the following jOOQ configuration:

```kotlin
private fun createConfiguration(dataSource: DataSource, loggerListener: JooqLoggerListener): Configuration {
    return DefaultConfiguration()
            .set(dataSource)
            .set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
            .set(DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(loggerListener))
            .set(Settings()
                    .withExecuteLogging(false) // We already use the custom [JooqLoggerListener].
                    .withParamType(ParamType.NAMED)
                    .withRenderFormatted(true)
                    .withRenderKeywordStyle(RenderKeywordStyle.UPPER)
                    .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.LOWER))
}
```

All settings are working except the `withParamType(ParamType.NAMED)`.

But logging the SQL in my custom `JooqLoggerListener` like:

```kotlin
override fun renderEnd(ctx: ExecuteContext) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled) {
        val configuration = ctx.configuration()
        val newline = if (configuration.settings().isRenderFormatted) "\n" else ""
        val inlined = DSL.using(configuration).renderInlined(ctx.query())
        logger.debug("Executing query:{}{}", newline, ctx.sql())
        logger.debug("Executing query (with bind values):{}{}", newline, inlined)
    }
}
```

Still prints question marks:

```
13:41:47.472 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG c.e.logging.JooqLoggerListener - Executing query:
SELECT 
  country.id, 
  country.alpha2_code, 
  country.alpha3_code, 
  country.name, 
  country.demonym, 
  country.continent_id
FROM country
WHERE country.id = ?
```

I would have expected something like:

```sql
WHERE country.id = :id
```

Is my assumption correct or is `withParamType(ParamType.NAMED)` used for something else?

Answer (score 3):

To use param names it is needed to provide the param name in the query.

I first had:

```
        return dslContext
                .selectFrom(COUNTRY)
                .where(COUNTRY.ID.eq(id))
                .fetchOneInto(Country::class.java)
```

After changing it to:

```
        return dslContext
                .selectFrom(COUNTRY)
                .where(COUNTRY.ID.eq(param("country_id", id)))
                .fetchOneInto(Country::class.java)
```

It worked!